# CP210x character device file not created on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, lsusb

I have attempted to connect two evaluation kits to my Ubuntu 22.04 System which have a Silabs CP210x chip on them. I was expecting to see a `/dev/ttyUSB` character device file when I plugged the USB cable into my system (as I did previously on an 18.04 system) without the need to manually load a kernel driver. However this didn't work.

- `lsusb` lists: `Bus 003 Device 024: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge`
- modinfo shows that the usbserial driver exists (/lib/modules/5.15.0-43-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/usbserial.ko
  )
- lsmod shows the correct drivers are loaded and being used:

```
lsmod | grep cp210x
cp210x                 40960  0
usbserial              57344  1 cp210x
```

- `lsusb -d 10c4:ea60 -v` returns:

```
Bus 003 Device 024: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x10c4 Silicon Labs
  idProduct          0xea60 CP210x UART Bridge
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Silicon Labs
  iProduct                2 CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
  iSerial                 3 0001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              2 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
```

Everything appears to be in order. So why wasn't a character device file created?

Answer (score 1):

`dmesg` revals the answer:

```
sudo dmesg | grep cp210x
[11475.182843] cp210x 3-11:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[11475.185804] usb 3-11: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[11479.400467] usb 3-11: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[11479.400838] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[11479.400850] cp210x 3-11:1.0: device disconnected
```

`brltty` is claming the device. The solution for me was just to remove brltty and unplug/plug the USB cable. I could have also disabled the `brltty` service [as mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670637/312932).